# To retain the form values in the jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a form that I am using for post the data

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label>Application Name <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="app_name" id="appname" required maxlength="40">
     <button>submit</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```

In flask i am fetching the form data and trying to do post method

```
if request.method == "POST":
   application_data = request.form.to_dict()
   postedata = post(application_data )
   if posteddata:
      print("sucessfully posted")
   else:
      print("unsucessful")
      return render_template("application/addapplication.html", data=application_data)
```

but what I want is when else part executes that means post data doesnot happens i want to retain the values in the form. but, since here page will reload the form data is disapperaring. please can anyone help me in this?

Comment: You must set the `value=""` attribute of the `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="{{ request.form.get('app_name','')}}" class="form-control" name="app_name" id="appname" required maxlength="40">
```

For Select tag, Let's take the data from the Flask flask_option = 'batman'.

```
<select>
  <option {% if flask_option == "superman"%} selected {% endif %} value="superman">Clark</option>
  <option {% if flask_option == "batman"%} selected {% endif %} value="batman">Bruce</option>
  <option {% if flask_option == "wonderwomen"%} selected {% endif %} value="wonderwomen">Diana</option>
  <option {% if flask_option == "aquaman"%} selected {% endif %} value="aquaman">Arthur</option>
</select>
```

If you are using API for the select options,
let's take the API response like this,

```
{'response': [
    {'value': 'superman', 'inner_text': 'Clark'},
    {'value': 'batman', 'inner_text': 'Bruce'},
    {'value': 'aquaman', 'inner_text': 'Arthur'},
    {'value': 'wonderwomen', 'inner_text': 'Diana'}
]}
```

You can iterate over the API to generate the select tag,

```
<select>
  {% for value, text in varible_name.response %}
     <option {% if flask_option == value %} selected {% endif %} value = '{{value}}'> {{text}} </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

For textarea, you can use

```
<textarea>{{reqest.form.get("txt")}}</textarea>
```

or javascript

```
$('textarea').text('{{reqest.form.get("txt")}}')
```

Comment: can u please tell how to retain the value if dropdown is there

Comment: what if i used text-area i hope we can't used request.form.get() i guess

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer navaneeth but the select box what you have sent i go through that link but I am not able to retain the values

Comment: <select>                                                                                                                     
         <option value="{{ data.tenant_id }}">{{ data.tenant_name }}</option>                                                                                                                      
</select>  this is my select box

Comment: This will give only one option

Comment: actually I am dynamically displaying the options which I got from api response

Comment: ya i am using that only

Comment: is there any error in that?  also, I have added my snippet, hope that will hep you